# Vuforia: OnTrackableStateChanged event not fired sometimes

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am developing an application using Unity and Vuforia SDK.

Application involves multiple markers.
I need to scan markers one by one in sequence.
When One marker is detected, OnTrackingFound event handler is called and OnTrackingLost event is fired when tracking is lost.

Issue is that when one marker is replaced with another marker, OnTrackerLost event is not fired.

Can we make OnTrackLost to be fired?

I analyzed the scenario and found that "OnTrackableStateChanged" event is not fired sometimes when Trackable is lost that is why OnTrackLost event is not fired.

Is there any solution so that OnTrackableStateChanged can be fired every time?

Note:  I use Unity and Vuforia version: 5.3.2

Following is the code I've used:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ImageTargetLoading : MonoBehaviour,ITrackableEventHandler
{
    private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;

void Start()
{
    mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
    if (mTrackableBehaviour)
    {
        mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
    }
}

public void OnTrackableStateChanged(TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus, TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
{
        if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED || newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED || newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
        {
            OnTrackingFound();
        }
        else
        {
            OnTrackingLost();
        }
}
}
```

"OnTrackableStateChanged" event is not fired sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

(This is more an answer to Hardik's response, since the original post was from 2016, before Vuforia 7.2.)

If you're using Vuforia 7.2 or later, Extended Tracking is enabled by default for all trackers: https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Extended-Tracking. (This is true as long as you have POSITIONAL tracking mode enabled for your device in the Vuforia Configuration window.)

I'm no Vuforia expert by a long shot, but it's possible that in that case, the state change is not to TrackableBehaviour.Status.NO_POSE but instead to TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED, which does NOT call the OnTrackingLost() method because Vuforia is still able to make a pretty decent assumption about where the tracker is, even if it can't actually track it.